# How to set Array Object Prototype for a Result Set of an Sql statement created with Sql object‏ in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I want to use the Sql object in my model to query the database. I have an entity object lets say Person and person object has `exchangeArray()` method. I want to set this Person object to be an `Array Object Prototype` of the ResultSet for my sql queries.

I research how to do this but the only information I found is how to set Array Object Prototype to a `ResultSet` object assigned to a `Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway`.

```
$personEntity = new PersonEntity();
$resultSet = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
$resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype($personEntity);
$db = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
$table = new \Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway('table', $db, null, $resultSet);
```

My question is how can I set `PersonEntity` object to represent rows of my database that are return from a `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql` objects?

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the following example will answer your question:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
    public function fetchAll() 
    {
        $sql = new Sql($dbAdapter); // Zend\Db\Sql\Sql
        $select = $sql->select('table_foo');
        $query = $sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $resutl = $query->execute();
        $resultSet = new ResultSet(); // Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet
        $resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype(new EntityObject()); // <-- HERE you set your entity object
        $resultSet->initialize($resutl);
        return $resultSet;
    }
    ...
}
```

This code will return a `ResultSet` object in which every row return will be repsresented by, in this case, `EntityObject`.

[Here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html#quickstart) is a reference to the manual that shows injection of the `dataSource` into a result object.

Answer (score 3):

You can set an array object prototype to any result set that you want like this:

```
$resultSet->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Entity);
```